# Angular2 error: Cannot create property 'validator' on number

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a form like following in my angula2/ionic2 app:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="subscribeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(subscribeForm.value)">
        ...

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Survey object size</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngFormControl]="size"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Survey object path</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngFormControl]="path" [(ngModel)]="path"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Survey object type</ion-label>
            <ion-select [ngFormControl]="type">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let type of survey_types">{{type}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>

        </ion-item>


        <br/><br/> 
        <button type="submit" class="custom-button" block>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

And I am handling it in my component as follows:

```
export class Subscription{

    subscribeForm: ControlGroup; 

    object_name: any;
    email: any;
    subscriber_name: any;
    size: any;
    path: any;
    cycle: AbstractControl;
    cycle_options=['ONCE', 'WEEKLY', 'MONTHELY']

    type: AbstractControl;
    survey_types=['FARM', 'SOLARPANEL', 'PLAIN']

    constructor(params: NavParams, private fb: FormBuilder) {

        this.size = params.get('size');
        this.path = params.get('path');

        this.subscribeForm = fb.group({
            'object_name': '',
            'email':'',
            'subscriber_name':'',
            'size':'',
            'path':'',
            'cycle':['', Validators.nullValidator],
            'object_type':['', Validators.nullValidator] 
        });

        this.object_name = this.subscribeForm.controls['object_name'];     
        this.email = this.subscribeForm.controls['email'];
        this.subscriber_name = this.subscribeForm.controls['subscriber_name'];
        this.cycle =  this.subscribeForm.controls['cycle'];
        this.type = this.subscribeForm.controls['type'];

    }

    onSubmit(value){

        console.log(value)
    }
}
```

With this I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on number '14808.18276685957'`

There are two select fields in my form, I am not sure if I am using them correctly and binding their value correctly in my component.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**UPDATE:** I am getting two NavParams and assigning their value to a form control so that the value is pre-populated. It looks like it's throwing some validation error `Cannot create property 'validator' on number '14772.975244232435'` which is for *path*

Comment: If you remove everything else, do you still get the error? If no, please remove the code that is not related to the error.

Comment: Updated my HTML snippet and also the question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `ngFormControl` to `ngControl` for size and path fields solved the problem.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Survey object size</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ngControl="size" [ngModel]="size" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Survey object path</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ngControl="path" [ngModel]="path"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

However, if someone could point out what's the difference between ngControl and ngFormControl, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use model form, you need to reference the field control this way:

```
<ion-input type="text"
   [ngFormControl]="subscribeForm.contrls.size"></ion-input>
```

The `ngFormControl` directive aims to reference an existing control.

Comment: What's the difference between ngControl and ngFormControl? because using ngControl actually solved my problem.

Comment: Also this solution threw me an error saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`